# Show contents of many files

Tags: command-line, files

From the command line, **what is the easiest way to show the contents of multiple files?** My directory looks like below.

```
./WtCgikkCFHmmuXQXp0FkZjVrnJSU64Jb9WSyZ52b
./xdIwVHnHY7dnuM9zcPDYQGZFdoVORPyMVD2IzjgM
./GZnATXO1e5Hh3Bz1bhgJjjwheIjjZqtnXR0hfOyj
./mWz7ehBNoTZmtDh8JG6sxw2lMJFwIovPzxDGECUY
./JN65F5v3RL2ilHPqNSx9N9D4lvVpqpbJ9lASd8TJ
./At9PS4y4nTiXUO0Z0USnbYkTPBla1msQRpwuruqE
./YiPyMZPCaUDZTiTczAvWII9bJrUqLXCFtH2pXEA2
./JoakdlbRFPwAvWp1d4n8RvMoyMeizCoiriL2Sn2U
./wFPWZUus8Yu7UtESGABLCoqDg36cT90USO0xuyUr
./qseI9PgV1EJfZCDyGGeVytajqG7JeX0r7eA5S1JW
./zgFJpNgXyCsaVh38aCuMGuzHwIbwSNB6rQDdh27x
./.htaccess
```

Now I'd like to view the contents of all files except `.htaccess`. It might look something like:

```
WtCgikkCFHmmuXQXp0FkZjVrnJSU64Jb9WSyZ52b:
Contents of file WtCgikkCFHmmuXQXp0FkZjVrnJSU64Jb9WSyZ52b.

xdIwVHnHY7dnuM9zcPDYQGZFdoVORPyMVD2IzjgM:
Contents of file xdIwVHnHY7dnuM9zcPDYQGZFdoVORPyMVD2IzjgM.

[...]
```

I think this should be doable with a combination of find, xargs and cat, but I haven't figured out how. Thanks for your time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917413/cat-multiple-files-but-include-filename-as-headers

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The standard `head` command and some implementations of `tail` print a header with the file name if you pass them more than one file argument (POSIX `tail` accepts only 0 or 1 file argument). To print the whole file, use `tail -n +1` (print from the first line onwards, i.e. everything).

Here, it looks like you want to see every file except the single one whose name begins with a dot. Dot files are “hidden” under unix: they don't appear in the default output of `ls` or in a wildcard match. So matching every non-hidden files is done with just `*`.

```
tail -n +1 -- *
```

Or if your `tail` can't take more than one argument:

```
head -n 999999 -- *
```

(some `head -n -0 -- *` but that's not standard either).

The GNU implementation of `head`/`tail` also accept a `-v`/`--verbose` option that ensures the header is printed even when only one filename is given.

`--` is needed to cover the cases where one of the file names begins with a `-`. Beware a file called `-` would still be taken by `head` / `tail` as meaning stdin. Using `./*` would work around it but would mean the `./` prefix would be included in the header on output.

Comment: Short and sweet, thank you! Do you know where I can read about the `--` modifier?

Comment: @Znarkus: `--` to signify the end of options is a convention that most commands obey. E.g. `tail -n +1 -- -f -g` tells `tail` that `-f` and `-g` are files to read (operands) and not options. It's guideline 10 in the [POSIX utility syntax guideline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02) (a document intended for utility writers). I don't have a reading suggestion intended for end-users, I'd expect a good unix tutorial to cover it at some point.

Comment: Just a remark, because many other answers propose to use `find`, but then use some exec with print formatting:

A simple way to use `find` and `tail`is:

`find . -type f -print0  -name "*" | xargs -0 tail -n +1 --`

(`-print0` and `xargs -0` and the `--` ensure that the command also works with filenames with spaces or starting with -)

Answer (score 26):

You can do it all in one with `find`:

```
$ find . -type f -not -name .htaccess -printf "\n%p\n" -exec cat {} \;
```

That tells `find` to find all files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.`) except (`-not`) one named `.htaccess` (`-name .htaccess`). Then it prints (`-printf`) a newline followed by the filename (`%p`), and then runs `cat` on the file (`-exec cat {} \;`). That will give you output like:

```
test/test3
Line 1

test/test2
Line 1

test/test1
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

---

If you do this often it might be worth sticking it in a shell script or a function; I have one named `cats` that does exactly that:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename; do
    echo "\033[32;1m$filename\033[0m"
    cat "$filename"
    echo
done
```

It loops over each filename argument, prints out the filename (in bold green), and then cats the file:

[image: Example screenshot]

So then the command would just be:

```
$ find . -type f -not -name .htaccess -exec cats {} \+
```

Comment: The other was shorter, so accepted that. Excellent answer though, thank you!

Comment: `-exec` can be used multiple times, I find this one more readable/tweakable: `find . -type f -exec echo === {} === \; -exec cat {} \;`

Answer (score 6):

To show content of all files in the current folder, try:

```
grep -vI "\x00" -- *
```

and similar, but recursively:

```
grep -vIr "\x00" -- .
```

The format would be: `filename: content`.

To have similar format as suggested, it would be:

```
grep -rvl "\x00" -- * | while read file; do printf "\n\n#### $file ####\n"; cat $file; done
```

Side notes:

- Using NUL (`\x00`) in above examples prevents displaying binary files (which `-I` is actually doing, but we've to still use some pattern).
- Using wildcard (`*`), it automatically ignores hidden files such as `.htaccess`.

See also: [grep: display filename once, then display context with line numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86180/21471) at Unix SE

Comment: Usually `grep -r ^` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
cat $(find Directory/ -not -name *.htaccess)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want too print it recursively use (for files with .sql extension, for example):

```
find -name "*.sql" -exec cat {} \; > all.sql
```